# What does the prefixed() function in SASS do?

Tags: function, sass, mixins

I have been trying to build my own gradient mixin in SASS based on the [background mixin from Compass](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/images/#mixin-background).

There is a line in the source that says the following:

```
$add-pie-bg: prefixed(-pie, $backgrounds) or $mult-bgs;
```

I have looked everywhere but I cant find reference to what the `prefixed` function does.

Can anybody shed a bit of light on this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Read the documentation](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/cross-browser/).

```
prefixed($prefix, $arg, ...)

Returns true if any of the arguments require the given prefix.
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Where is the documentation for this function. I checked the [SASS documentation](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Script/Functions.html)

Comment: It's a Compass function not straight Sass, there is a link to it in my answer.